# SVN checkout issue with totrtoise svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I Just installed Tortoise SVN and i am takingmy first checkout from the repository so i go to my local directory and there i right click and and select svn checkout

and there i enter my repository and local directory address and i click the checkout button 
I provide my user credentials and i get this error message

```
Command: Checkout from http://180.149.243.244:8080/scm/svn/foodie, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included  
Error: Unexpected HTTP status 500 'Server Error' on '/scm/svn/foodie/!svn/vcc/default'  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: svn: Invalid revision number '-1'  
Completed!:
```

Some please help.

I am using Windows 8

Comment: Your OS version isn't as important as the Subversion version you're running on both server and client. What versions are you running?

Comment: For your server, ask your server admin. For the client, use TortoiseSVN -> About (just like most any other Windows software)